# How to unpack a tuple right from out parameter?

Tags: c#, tuples, argument-unpacking

Let's say I have a dictionary with points. So I could then write:

```
if (dict.TryGetValue(key,out (double x,double y) point))
  point.x ...
```

But how do get rid of `point` and unpack the elements of the tuple right away? I have something like this in mind:

```
if (dict.TryGetValue(key,out (out double x,out double y)))
  x ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems currently it is not possible based on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/611) opened issue.

In terms of deconstructing the best option, I think, you have is to do it in two steps:

```
if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out var point))
{
    (double x, double y) = point;
    ...
}
```